# Error deploying LWC in change-set. Programmer error: Cannot compare savepoints from two different transactions

Tags: lightning-web-components, deployment, exception, change-set

I have two Lightning Web Components that consistently fail when I try to deploy them in a change-set. The two LWC are the only components being added in the CS and the error is consistent. Everything that the LWC's need are included and everything runs fine in the outbound org.

[image: Deploy Error]

**Errors:**

Programmer error: Cannot compare savepoints from two different transactions Field info: entity name = LightningComponentResource, field name = Source.

Package Installation Failure

**Notification:**

Fatal Error
LIMIT_EXCEEDED: Try deploying again. Your deployment exceeded its maximum retry limit. If you keep seeing this error, please contact Salesforce Customer Support.
Component Errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Salesforce BUG
Reference W-7720372
Update: November 17, 2020
A fix has been submitted for this issue. Enablement of the fix requires you to contact Salesforce Support and ask that the fix be applied to your Organization that is encountering the issue.

There is an issue with the transaction management on the changeset deployment for Lightning Web Components and Aura components containing Lightning Message Channel.

The above types of components cannot be deployed using changesets presently due to the fatal error below:

Issue Description:
"Fatal Error Programmer error: Cannot compare savepoints from two different transactions Field info: entity name = LightningComponentResource, field name = Source"

Users will notice an unusual behavior during validation/deployment on the UI, where it looks like it's reverting back after completion and re-trying before it fails with the above error. This operation can take a long time even with a small number of components being deployed.

Message Channel, on its own, can be deployed through changesets

Another symptom is Managed-package Patch orgs showing as "Creating" indefinitely.

Repro

1. Deploy a Message Channel into the org using any deployment method
2. Create an inbound changeset with either LWC or Aura referencing the message channel and upload to target org
3. In the target org, validate or deploy the above changeset from inbound changesets
4. Notice the unusual behavior during validation/deployment and see the fatal error.

Workaround
Use any deployment method aside from changesets to deploy components containing Lightning Message Channel.

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000000KT74QAG&title=change-set-deployment-is-stuck-in-in-progress

Comment: While we have moved on from this issue this is a thorough and appreciated response.